# Using generics without declaring them as parameter

Tags: typescript, redux

I am writing some redux middleware with an simplified version below:

```
const api = {
  createStuff (params: object): Promise<{someAttr: true}> { ... }
}

export const createChannel = (params: object): ApiAction => {
    return {
        transform: (payload) => ({ ...payload, anotherField: 123 }), // Here I would like to be able to autocomplete the someAttr specified in the function signature above
        call: (api) => api.createStuff(params) // the above api object is injected here by the middleware
    };
};
```

The middleware will take the result of the `call` function and pass it to the `transform` callback.

I'd like to automatically infer the type of the to-be transformed `payload` based on the function signature of the `createStuff` function

I figured I'd do something like

I have the following interface

```
export interface ApiAction<R> {
    transform? (R): object
    callApi (object): Promise<R>
}
```

But here I need to explicitly declare the `R` type. I'd rather have it automatically inferred

Is this possible?

Comment: You mean automatically inferred as in you don't have to say `ApiAction<SomeType>`, just `ApiAction` and the interface will just know that the transform is of type `SomeType` and the Promise is  a`Promise<SomeType>`?

Comment: It's not exactly clear to me what is being asked for here; existential types, maybe? Could you be more specific about what you want, and maybe clean up the code? (e.g., is `createStuff()` a standalone function or a method of `api`? Does it return a `{ someAttr: true }` or a `Promise`?  What types are `payload` and `api`?  Is it `call()` or `callApi()`? Et cetera)

Comment: @vincecampanale exactly

Comment: @jcalz I've cleaned up the code a bit, sorry about that

Comment: Will you need to reuse `ApiAction<R>` with different values of `R` in your application? Or is it that there's just one type of `R` but it's defined indirectly by `api` and you want a programmatic way to extract it? Or something else?  Plus, I'm looking at your code, and I still have to alter it to make it compile or make sense. Your interface is not valid TypeScript, since function signatures require named parameters (although the names are not used in type checking; they're dummy or hint values); and the method `callApi()` is not the same name as `call()`.